# 2 or 3 line border in html,css,bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create 2/3 line colorful border on a div or header.
I need this type of structure like this picture same to same

[image: this picture]

Using html,css and bootstrap . 
i can't do this , please somebody help !!

Comment: set a background-color, then set a border and set an outline using css ,

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code (HTML/CSS/JS) you're working with in a Snippet. [mcve]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach for how to achieve this :

```css
/*-- Style example 1 --*/
.container{
   background-color: #DFBA8A;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 5px solid #8ECE8E;
   padding: 5px;
 }

.inner{
   border: 5px solid #CACE8E;
   background-color: #BBBF00 ;
 }

h1{
   color: #FFF;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 15px 20px;
 }

/*-- Style example 2 --*/
.container-2{
   margin-top: 10px;
   background-color: #BBBF00;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 6px;
 }

.inner-2{
   border: 5px solid #CACE8E;
 }

h1{
   color: #FFF;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 15px 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Example 1 -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner">
     <h1>WE ARE THE SKOOL</h1>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Example 2 -->
<div class="container-2">
   <div class="inner-2">
     <h1>WE ARE THE SKOOL</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{background-color:#FFCC66;color:white;font-size:20pt;border: 4px solid #CC6600;outline: 3px solid #996633; width:100px}
```

```html
<div class="main">SKOOL</div>
```

[See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ap4e4c6p/)

Comment: mine actually has 3 colors, all in the same element, just sayin